# Horizontal timeline with video playing on the background

Tags: html, css

a newbie here. 
I just have a few question regarding an experiment.
I have seen this website and I am totally in love with the video bg and the timeline with popups.

[vitrachairs](https://taskchairs.vitra.com/en-gb/am/timeline)

I have followed a tutorial and when I tried to add the video it didn't cover the whole page. I am wondering how can I do something similar. 
I would be grateful!

https://codepen.io/basma1234/pen/mqpKoa

I'm guessing that I should change something in the css.

```
.fullscreen-bg {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0; 
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%; 
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; 
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
}
```